# Why win32api can not scan keys after filedialog was used in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, tkinter

After using "askdirectory" from Tkinter in Python 3 I win32api.GetKeyState() doesn't work.

Hello there!

In Python 3 I am trying to catch keys that were pressed to make several actions in my tool. The logic looks like this:
1. I select a folder to save results.
2. I catch key strokes and do some actions.
3. I save results in the folder.

To select a folder I use "askdirectory" from tkinter.
To scan keys I use win32api.GetKeyState()

When I am trying to scan keys without calling askdirectory, everything works fine. If I call askdirectory and then try to scan keys, win32api.GetKeyState() shows static results. It seems that win32api can not get results anymore.

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

The code below fails on my machine. If I make "folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Tilte")" a comment - everything works great.

Thanks in advance.

```
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
def scan_keys():
    import win32api

    roll = True
    base_left_mouse = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    base_shift = win32api.GetKeyState(0x10)
    base_ctrl = win32api.GetKeyState(0x11)
    base_alt = win32api.GetKeyState(0x12)
    base_p = win32api.GetKeyState(0x50)

    while roll:
        print("Scanning keys")
        print(base_left_mouse, base_shift, base_ctrl, base_alt, base_p)
        left_mouse = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        shift = win32api.GetKeyState(0x10)
        ctrl = win32api.GetKeyState(0x11)
        alt = win32api.GetKeyState(0x12)
        p = win32api.GetKeyState(0x50)
        if (alt<0 and p!=base_p):
            print("ALT + P is pressed")

        elif (ctrl<0 and alt<0 and p!=base_p):
            print("Gathering complete")
            roll = False

        base_left_mouse = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
        base_shift = win32api.GetKeyState(0x10)
        base_ctrl = win32api.GetKeyState(0x11)
        base_alt = win32api.GetKeyState(0x12)
        base_p = win32api.GetKeyState(0x50)
        print("Scanning base keys")
        time.sleep(1)

root=tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Tilte")
print(folder)
scan_keys()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but calling `root.destroy()` before `scan_keys()` (and leaving out `root.mainloop()`) seems to fix this. I'm guessing it has something to do with the running Tcl interpreter, but I'm absolutely not sure.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, root.destroy() - works fine. Another solution that I use now is to create a separate thread with keys listener. However, it is so strange that you need to do this :)

Comment: Why do you need to use win32api? Why not use tkinter's native key binding mechanism?

Comment: Use the `GetAsyncKeyState` instead of `GetKeyState` also get work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of `GetKeyState` depends on the current message queue,

> it reports the state of the keyboard based on the messages you have
>   retrieved from your input queue.

(From [The old new thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041130-00/?p=37173))

If the current message queue has been changed, The key message will be sent to the new queue, and the message in the old one is Invalid.(unless you back to the old queue).

`GetAsyncKeyState` return the status reflect the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware.
And you also need to ignore the least significant bit:

```
base_x = win32api.GetKeyState(key)&0x8000
```

Comment: Thank you all! 
I used "pynput" in my case. And I have checked the answer from @drake-wu-msft, it works. Thanks a lot for that!
As some clarification, I didn't use bindings just because I need to check what keys I press when the mouse is on GUI of another application. I was sure that binding fails in this case.

Comment: Wu. Thanks for a reminder. I checked it as an answer.